# How can i make custom border corners using images in css/html?

Tags: html, css

Is there any good way i can have custom corners like that?

Height will change depends how much text is inside, width can be constant, don't care.

html

```
    <table class="npc_chat_div" style="width: 80%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr>
    <td style="width:11px;"><div class="t1" style="display:block;width:45px;height:47px;position:absolute;top:28px;"></div></td>
    <td style="width:85px;"><div class="t2" style="display:block;width:85px;height:31px;"></div></td>
    <td style="width:100%;"><div class="t3" style="display:block;width:100%;height:11px;"></div></td>
    <td style="width:11px;"><div class="t4" style="display: block;width: 47px;height: 45px;position: absolute;top: 28px;right: 8px;"></div></td>
  </tr><tr class="m_tr">
    <td class="m1"></td>
    <td colspan="2" class="m2">

<div class="m3" style="overflow:auto;background:transparent;border:none;min-height:12px;height:100%;"><span>
<p>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br><span>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br><span>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br><span>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br><span>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br></div>

    </td>
    <td class="m4"></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td class="b1" style="width:11px;"><div style="display:block;width:11px;height:24px;"></div></td>
    <td class="b2" style="width:85px;"><div style="display:block;width:85px;height:24px;"></div></td>
    <td class="b3" style="width:100%;"><div style="display:block;width:100%;height:24px;"></div></td>
    <td class="b4" style="width:11px;"><div style="display:block;width:11px;height:24px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

css

```
.npc_chat_div_r td, .npc_chat_div td {
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t3, .npc_chat_div .t3 {
    color: #002bb8 !important;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 80%;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .m3, .npc_chat_div .m3 {
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t3 > a, .npc_chat_div .t3 > a {
    color: #002bb8 !important;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t1, .npc_chat_div .t1 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/uWGaaat.png');
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t2, .npc_chat_div .t2 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/phPB10t.png');
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t3, .npc_chat_div .t3 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/2fIrT0n.png');
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t4, .npc_chat_div .t4 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/48YiCrA.png');
}
.npc_chat_div_r .m1, .npc_chat_div .m1 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/JuJ5shQ.png');
}
.npc_chat_div_r .m4, .npc_chat_div .m4 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/QcpyKdi.png');
}
.npc_chat_div_r .b1, .npc_chat_div .b1 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/hcl2E9G.png');
}
.npc_chat_div_r .b2, .npc_chat_div .b2 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/U6N8SN3.png');
}
.npc_chat_div_r .b3, .npc_chat_div .b3 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/U6N8SN3.png') repeat-x;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .b4, .npc_chat_div .b4 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ePuqEJF.png');
}
/** Plain style **/
.npc_chat_div_r a {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
.npc_chat_div_r p {
    margin: 0px;
}
.npc_chat_div_r span.pl {
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: bold
}
.npc_chat_div_r span.pl>span.i {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal !important
}
.npc_chat_div_r .m3 {
    font: 11px/14px Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
/** Tibia style */
.npc_chat_div a {
    color: #A8E051 !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
.npc_chat_div b {
    color: #25FFBA;
}
.npc_chat_div p {
    margin: 0px;
}
.npc_chat_div span.pl a {
    color: #3D7F8E !important;
}
.npc_chat_div span.pl b, .npc_chat_div span.pl i {
    color: #3D7F8E;
    font-style: normal;
}
.npc_chat_div span.pl {
    color: #3D7F8E;
}
.npc_chat_div span.pl > span.i {
    font-style: italic;
}
.npc_chat_div .m2 {
    background: #050F17;
}
.npc_chat_div .m3 {
    color: #A8E051;
    font: bold 11px/14px Tahoma, sans-serif;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #1D1D1D;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #434343;
    scrollbar-face-color: #444444;
    scrollbar-drakshadow-color: #1D1D1D;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #949494;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #8E8E8E;
    scrollbar-track-color: #373837;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Heres the part effect i want to accomplish.
It doesn't have to be table.

https://jsfiddle.net/su6wbgd2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forced it to work, probably in bad way but still...

HTML

```
<div class="m3" style="overflow:auto;background:transparent;border:none;min-height:12px;height:100%;"><span>
<p>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br><span>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br><span>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br><span>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br><span>
<i>NPC</i>: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla <b>bla</b>.</span><br><span>
</span><span class="pl"><span class="i">Player</span>: <b> bla bla</b></span><br></div>

    </td>
    <td class="m4"></td>
  </tr><tr>
    <td class="b1" style="width:11px;"><div></div></td>
    <td class="b2" style="width:85px;"><div style="display:block;width:85px;height:24px;"></div></td>
    <td class="b3" style="width:100%;"><div style="display:block;width:100%;height:24px;"></div></td>
    <td class="b4" style="width:11px;"><div></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.npc_chat_div_r td, .npc_chat_div td {
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t3, .npc_chat_div .t3 {
    color: #002bb8 !important;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 80%;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .m3, .npc_chat_div .m3 {
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t3 > a, .npc_chat_div .t3 > a {
    color: #002bb8 !important;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t1, .npc_chat_div .t1 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/uWGaaat.png') no-repeat;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t2, .npc_chat_div .t2 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/WcihOkH.png') no-repeat;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t3, .npc_chat_div .t3 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/2fIrT0n.png') repeat-x;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .t4, .npc_chat_div .t4 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/48YiCrA.png') no-repeat;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .m1, .npc_chat_div .m1 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/JuJ5shQ.png') repeat-y;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .m4, .npc_chat_div .m4 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/QcpyKdi.png') repeat-y;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .b1, .npc_chat_div .b1 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -34px;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .b1, .npc_chat_div .b1 > div {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/hcl2E9G.png') no-repeat;
    width: 45px;
    height: 47px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .b2, .npc_chat_div .b2 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/U6N8SN3.png') repeat-x;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .b3, .npc_chat_div .b3 {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/U6N8SN3.png') repeat-x;
}
.npc_chat_div_r .b4, .npc_chat_div .b4 > div {
  display: block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 47px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/ePuqEJF.png') no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  top: -36px;
  right: 34px;
}

/** Plain style **/
.npc_chat_div_r a {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
.npc_chat_div_r p {
    margin: 0px;
}
.npc_chat_div_r span.pl {
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-weight: bold
}
.npc_chat_div_r span.pl>span.i {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal !important
}
.npc_chat_div_r .m3 {
    font: 11px/14px Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
/** Tibia style */
.npc_chat_div a {
    color: #A8E051 !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
.npc_chat_div b {
    color: #25FFBA;
}
.npc_chat_div p {
    margin: 0px;
}
.npc_chat_div span.pl a {
    color: #3D7F8E !important;
}
.npc_chat_div span.pl b, .npc_chat_div span.pl i {
    color: #3D7F8E;
    font-style: normal;
}
.npc_chat_div span.pl {
    color: #3D7F8E;
}
.npc_chat_div span.pl > span.i {
    font-style: italic;
}
.npc_chat_div .m2 {
    background: #050F17;
}
.npc_chat_div .m3 {
    color: #A8E051;
    font: bold 11px/14px Tahoma, sans-serif;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #1D1D1D;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #434343;
    scrollbar-face-color: #444444;
    scrollbar-drakshadow-color: #1D1D1D;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #949494;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #8E8E8E;
    scrollbar-track-color: #373837;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/su6wbgd2/1/

Answer (score 1):

The fiddle you linked to **uses images** to achieve the effect. See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOlRx.png)

If you don't mind something a bit less complex for a corner, you can achieve that with `CSS`.

Here's a great example by **I.M. Skeer** on **CodePen** all credit goes back to him/her:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div.bite {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid white 4px;
  padding: 35px;
}
.top,
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.top:before,
.top:after,
.bottom:before,
.bottom:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #000;
  border: solid white 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.top:before {
  top: -35px;
  left: -35px;
}
.top:after {
  top: -35px;
  right: -35px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px white;
}
.bottom:before {
  bottom: -35px;
  left: -35px;
}
.bottom:after {
  bottom: -35px;
  right: -35px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bite">
    <div class="top">&nbsp;</div>
    <p>Anything you like to put in here</p>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the link to the original [CodePen](http://codepen.io/imskeer/pen/kCIxv) page